I have send out my first mail campaign, when clicking on report I get a permission error,
I send out my first mailing today, it went out ok.
But when I click on ANY of the reports I get (even though I am admin):
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
You do not have permission to access this page.

I can't see any errors in the PHP error log,but I can see a 404 in the apache access log:
[08/Dec/2024:21:07:13 +1100] "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Freport%2Finstance%2F34&reset=1&mailing_id_value=46 HTTP/1.1" 403 19327 "/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fmailing%2Freport&mid=46&reset=1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" TLSv1.2 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

Why do I get access denied?

I fixed it, CiviReport was not installed.
Now some feedback for the people at CiviCRM:
The error message produced by CiviCRM are at times rather misleading.
Proper error checks could have saved me some time.
What happened:

I sent out my first mailout
After mailout had finished I clicked on "Sent Mailings"
I then selected Reports of the Mailing just sent
Then clicked on "Reports" for the bounces
I received "You do not have permission to access this page."

What SHOULD have happened

I sent out my first mailout
After mailout had finished I clicked on "Sent Mailings"
I then selected Reports of the Mailing just sent
AT this stage I should have received a WARNING "CiviReports not installed"
Then clicked on "Reports" for the bounces
Again AT this stage I should have received a WARNING "CiviReports not installed"

